# Is my estimate good enough?

Tags: calculus

Im trying to prove that $$ \frac{t^2 x }{t^4 + x^2 } \to 0 $$ as $(t,x) \to (0,0)$ usin $\delta-\epsilon$ proof.

supose $|t| < \delta $, $|x| < \delta $ .we want to find those deltas such that

$$ \left| \frac{t^2 x }{t^4 + x^2 } \right | < \epsilon $$

we know

$$ \left| \frac{t^2 x }{t^4 + x^2 } \right| \leq \frac{ t^2 |x| }{t^2 + x^2 } \leq \frac{|x| }{1} < \delta $$

Is this estimate good?

Comment: This function is an example of a limit of two variables. We have:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^2 x}{t^4 +x^2} = 
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^2 x}{t^4 +x^2} = 0
$$
But, 
$$
\lim_{\substack{x\rightarrow 0 \\ t\rightarrow 0}}\frac{t^2 x}{t^4 +x^2}
$$
does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. For every $1>\delta>0$ we can find $t,x$ such that $|t|,|x|\le\delta$ and $\left|\frac{t^2x}{t^4+x^2}\right|\ge\epsilon$. Indeed, simply select $x=\delta^2$ and $t=\delta$.

---

Note that in your calculation, you made the following mistake:
$$
\left|\frac{t^2x}{\color{red}{t^4}+x^2}\right|\le\frac{t^2|x|}{\color{red}{t^2}+x^2}
$$
which is only true for $|t|\ge1$.

Comment: the reasong you pick $\delta < 1$ is it because this holds for any $\delta $?we may also choose $\delta = 1$ right??

Comment: To prove convergence of $f(x,t)$ at $0$ in $\delta$-$\epsilon$ terms, we must show that "for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $|t|,|x|\le\delta$ implies $|f(x,t)|\le\epsilon$."
or in logical terms: $$\forall{(\epsilon\gt0)}\exists{(\delta\gt0)}\forall{(|x|,|t|\le\delta)} : |f(x,t)|\lt\epsilon$$

To disprove it we must show that: $$\exists{(\epsilon\gt0)}\forall{(\delta\gt0)}\exists{(|x|,|t|\le\delta)} : |f(x,t)|\ge\epsilon$$, i.e. "there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$ we can find some $|x|,|t|\le\delta$ for which $|f(x,t)| \le\epsilon$.

Comment: I agree but I see your choices of $x,t$ dont work. Indeed, if $x = \delta^2$ and $t = \delta$, then $|f(x,t)| = \frac{1}{2 \delta} $ which we cant show its grater than 1/2

Comment: I required that $0<\delta<1$ since this implies $|x|=\delta^2\lt\delta$. It is sufficient to select $0<\delta<1$, since any $t,x$ that work for these $\delta$'s will also work for $\delta\ge1$.

Comment: I dont see why you can assume $\delta < 1$. This is supposed to hold for all $\delta$

Comment: maybe we shuold pick $x = min( \delta^2, 1 )$ and $t = min(\delta, 1 )$

Comment: Requiring that $0<\delta<\nu$ for some $\nu>0$ is equivalent to the original statement. This is because our requirement of $\delta$ is that there are $x,t$ with the desired properties whose absolute size is smaller than $\delta$ . If we can find such $t,x$ for $\delta<\nu$ the same $t,x$ could also be used for $\delta\ge\nu$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it does not.  If you set $x=t^2$, then you get $\frac{t^4}{2t^4}=\frac{1}{2}$.  As $t\rightarrow0$, this is a constant $\frac{1}{2}$ so that no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, you can find a small enough $t$ so that $(x, t)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $(0, 0)$ but your function is not close to $0$.

Comment: And with $x=-t^2$ the limit is $-\frac12$. These are already the extrema of the range, as $|xt^2|\le\frac12(x^2+t^4)$ by binomial identity or arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.